# Multiple x number from user-input using for-loop or while-loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, user-input

I have 2-column table. 1st row from the left table show label "Enter X (Number)" and input field type="number" next to it. 2nd row "Show X" for how much Multiple X will be displayed, and the 3rd row for output/result.

## Example:

#### User-Input

- Enter X(number): 10
- Show X : 7

#### Result (output)

10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70

how to do this with for-loop?
how to do this using while-loop with the same result?

Comment: The task is very easy. You can (you should) implement it by yourself. You can find any required tutorials and manuals just surf a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showValues() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var outputString = "" + (num1);
    for (var count = 2; count <= num2; count++) {
       outputString += ", " + (num1 * count); 
    }
    document.getElementById("theAnswer").value = outputString;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table id="tableid">

<tr>
<td>Enter X(number):</td> <td><input id="input1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Show X:</td> <td><input id="input2" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> answer </td> <td><input id="theAnswer" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>


<button type="button" onclick="showValues();">showValues<br/>
</div>
</body></html>
```